# Is it possible to open PDF files one after other, their names are saved in a text file using Python?

Tags: python

I wanted to open PDF files one after other to take screenshots with a delay of n seconds.I have made a "1.txt" file to open these through python. I have read these names to a list. But Is there way to read this list to open the files with delay?

## I am disconnected here to get the list of the drawings from the list to open it through loop with a delay.

```
linelist=[line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('1.txt')
print(linelist)
pdf_file=open('1.pdf','rb')
read_pdf=PyPDF2.pdfFileReader(pdf_file)
```

## This is the place I am stuck, to get the file names in the list looped to opening them. used PyPDF2, Webbrowser modules

```
wb.open_new(r'C\test\1.pdf')
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to open them with your default pdf viewer or within python?

Comment: I wanted open these in external reader through python. My purpose is to take screenshots of certain portions of them.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a list in python you can do `for element in list`.

Also, to generate the images from the `pdf` files, you can use python's pdf2image module, as in this [link](https://simply-python.com/2018/11/15/convert-pdf-pages-to-jpeg-with-python/).

The complete solution would look like:

```
import os
import tempfile
from pdf2image import convert_from_path


with open('1.txt', 'r') as f:
    line_list = f.read().splitlines()

print(line_list)

for line in line_list:

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
         images_from_path = convert_from_path(line, output_folder='./', 
                                              last_page=1, first_page =0)

    base_filename  =  os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(line))[0] + '.jpg'     

    save_dir = './'

    for page in images_from_path:
        page.save(os.path.join(save_dir, base_filename), 'JPEG')
```

Comment: Thanks, jpnadas! 
The code did not throw any error, but I fear that the PDF files did not open in the reader.

Comment: @ShinoySivan, what exactly do you want to do with the file? Open it in the system pdf viewer?

Comment: I have few thousands of pdfs to take screenshots from!
So I need them to open one after other with a delay to take a screenshots as most of them are scanned pdfs which will not allow me to extract the text from it.

I modified the code you gave little bit with another module webbrowser

Comment: import PyPDF2
import webbrowser as wb

with open('1.txt', 'r') as f:
    line_list = f.read().splitlines()

print(line_list)

for line in line_list:
    with wb.open(line, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

Comment: What OS are you running? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve your end goal, which if I understood correctly is to get images of several PDF files, correct?

Comment: I am running Win 10. My end goal is to extract a particular information from the PDF screenshots as many of these are rotated in different direction making me to take take two screenshots of same PDF with two different areas where this particular data is written.  

I was thinking to extract the data from the Screen shots or I am unaware of getting the data directly from scanned PDF. :(

Comment: You should take a look at this link https://simply-python.com/2018/11/15/convert-pdf-pages-to-jpeg-with-python/. They suggest using a module called pdf2image.

Comment: I have edited the answer for a complete solution, check it out @ShinoySivan

Answer (score 0):

This uses commandline to open the file, which opens it in the default viewer. Tested on Windows 10.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([filename], shell=True)
```

To use your own code:

```
import subprocess
import time

sleepytime = 5

linelist=[line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('1.txt')
print(linelist)
for filename in linelist:
    subprocess.Popen([filename], shell=True)
    time.sleep(sleepytime)
```

Of course I would advise you to look at a way to automate also the screenshot part. Making your life so much more fun.

For example using the [pdf2image library](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image)

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
images = convert_from_path('/home/belval/example.pdf')
for image in images:
    image.save('image.jpg', 'JPEG')  # <- change this
```